# What do I do in a Radiation Storm?

Tags: fallout-4

Every couple of days or so a huge Radiation Storm blows through the area that I'm currently in. How do I decrease my chances of contracting RADS if I'm outside?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but does putting on one of those breathing masks work?

Comment: @z'  Oh you know what, that's a good point. I never switched to a full hazmat suit in a  storm before. I'm always in a freaking gun battle with raiders or ghouls when these storms hit me.

Comment: Gas masks do help since they have Radiation resistance. I put one on during a storm and was taking reduced amount of RADS when lightning struck.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best solution I found to this is to use fast travel to travel to the nearest thing you've discovered.  Or perhaps the second nearest.  The point is to use it as a way to pass time, but not to make you travel far away from what you're doing.

So far for me, that makes the storm pass and no rads are absorbed.

Per your comment about being hit by these storms in gun fights, this won't help in those cases since you need to be a little ways away from hostiles in order to fast travel.  But if you can break off from the fight (become hidden) or end it quickly, the fast travel will still be of use.

Also, as kalina mentioned in their answer, a radiation suit will help.  There's a free Hazmat Suit with 1000 Radiation resistance in the Cambridge Polymer Lab. Here's the CPL's location:

[image: CPL Location]

I didn't think to take a screenshot of the Hazmat suit's specific location. The Hazmat Suit itself is on the first floor, in a room across from Ericka's lab(where you mix ingredients plus an isotope), and sits on top of a shelf in the corner.  Below is where I think the hazmat suit was, but again I forgot to screenshot before picking it up.

[image]

Having such a suit will allow you to do some exploring in the open world during a rad storm, but as mentioned in the other answer it comes at the cost of your armor stats.

Comment: If there is one  close by, you can also duck into an indoor location duck into it till the storm passes.  A common problem is running into a storm right after you leave vault 111.  In that case the best solution is to go back to the middle of the platform which will take you back into the vault.  In sanctuary there is also a root cellar behind one of the houses that you can hide in.

Comment: @Red_Tractor +1 for the root cellar, didn't know about that.  You can also sleep for an hour, and radiation storms usually pass.

Comment: You can also just go to sleep if there is an open bed nearby. You just have to hit the action when you are not taking Rads. Sleep for at least a couple hours and you will be fine, no rads taken while sleeping.

Comment: A hazmat suit for a radiation storm is some serious overkill.

Answer (score 21):

Radiation storms are not all that dangerous. At most, I usually soak up about 60-100 RADs. Easily curable with a paltry 40 caps at a settlement doctor. If you are earlier in the game, the best things to do are:

1. **Hop in your power armor and wait it out**
   Whether it has a charged fusion core or not, any power armor will add hundreds to your RAD Resistance, which is more than enough to completely negate the minor bursts of radiation from a storm. Most storms pass in about 60 seconds or so, so just buckle up and wait it out. Fusion core power is only drained by movement and combat actions, so if you sit still and refrain from doing anything, you can sit through the storm without depleting your valuable cores.
2. **Hide in an "out-map" area** 
   An out-map area is any area that requires you to load out of the "Commonwealth" over-map. Structure interiors, vaults, certain caves, etc. There are very few exceptions, such as areas that require a load, where you remain outdoors. The downside of out-map areas is that you can not tell if the storm has passed. Storms can vary in duration, and are fairly frequent. You may end up waiting, only to emerge into an entirely new storm, but this is not a common occurrence.
3. **Carry a radiation suit with you everywhere**
   Similar to power armor, a radiation suit offers an inordinate degree of RAD resistance, and can shield you from a radiation storm. However, carrying it with you always eats up precious inventory weight, that might be better spent carrying junk. It might also be a hassle to rush to equip the suit, only to re-equip your original gear about 60 seconds later. This becomes especially cumbersome when you use pieced armor such as raider, leather or metal.
4. **Fast Travel**
   Arguably the easiest solution. Simply fast travel to a nearby location, then back again, and the storm will have passed. If that spot happens to be in the middle of nowhere, try placing a map marker, before your first fast travel. This will allow you to hone in on your exact previous location. Other downsides to this include spawning into a repopulated area, which means fighting on arrival. Also, if there are corpses you have not looted when you travel away, they may despawn by the time you return.

Comment: It seems like coming across interesting and irradiated areas is more common than in 3 and New Vegas. A hazmat suit only weighs 5, so if you can spare the space, rads you get are basically negligible and makes exploring dangerously radioactive areas fairly convenient, without using fusion cores on simple exploration outings.

Answer (score 4):

You could wear a radiation suit but it would come at a penalty of all of the stats you get from your armor. Wearing a radiation suit would effectively protect yourself from any radiation.

It is also possible to gain radiation resistance from armor which would reduce the amount of RADs gained. For temporary resistance to radiation you can also take Rad-X.

The collectable book Astoundingly Awesome 10 (available from the church near Trinity Plaza) adds a +5 radiation resistance.

Comment: Taking Rad-X is another solution.

Answer (score 3):

Radiation storms actually don't hit you with a great deal of radiation. You'll take more simply fighting with ghouls. If you're doing something that you'd rather not interrupt, I recommend you simply keep going. Also note, it's always helpful to consider armor with a bit of radiation protection. Many types have at least some radiation in addition to ballistics and electrical. Make sure you consider this instead of simply taking the armor with the greatest ballistics defense. If all else fails - find a bed or the often overlooked seat. You can sleep in a bed and simply wait in any seat and allow time to pass.

Comment: Yeah, they're really nothing to worry about. Besides armor with rad resistance, simply wearing the vault suit around will nerf the storms quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, best solution seems to be 'fast travel away, fast travel back'.

I've tried waiting one out in Concord (first time I encountered it was when I was first exploring that town), waited out in a chair (inside one of the buildings that switches you out of the main map) for 3 days, storm was still outside.  I've also went into the water treatment plant when a storm was outside and by the time I finished the mission the storm was gone.  No clue what the logic behing it all is.

I've also tried going into buildings with roofs on them - unless the map swaps out you still get radiated so that doesn't seem to help any.

So now I just fast travel out and then back in.  They don't add anything neat beyond the overall appearance (which is cool but already seen it) so not worth bringing up my rad count if I absolutely have to (though I'll go nab that suit in case I'm ever forced to deal with one)

Answer (score 0):

You have various options when caught in a radstorm.
The ones I prefer are listed:
1. Find a bed in an enclosed area or where ever you have made your own bed that isn't owned by someone else, sleep for about 2 to 3 hours and from time to time it will make the storm pass.
2. Wear some power armor. The rad resistance is pretty high with any power armor you might find. The same goes for a radiation suit (You could possibly wear both, however, I'm not sure if that works).
3. Find shelter in a vault or underground area. Try to find a chair or anything to wait it out. Eventually the storm should subside.
These storms usually don't last too long but they lead to heavy fog or rain afterward so just be prepared for that.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing is to sleep for 1 hour (if you're somewhere around beds) or fast travel to a close location and back again... It's still strange that you get rad dmg in buildings without holes in the roof - it would have been nice to be able to hide...

Comment: Unless your house was lead, I don't think a solid roof  would be good enough anyway...haha

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is sleep, you get no RADS and you can just sleep it off and feel well rested. (I slept for 24 hrs to let the storm completely pass over.

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to hide from all the rads without suits or out of map locations however hiding behind or inside buildings or walls that are structurally intact or very well built it won't get rid of rad absorbtion But helps reduce the amount Think of a jug holding water... the better its built and put together the more it keeps in also it seems certain locations get the worst of the storm but i have yet to see a rad storm legitamitely kill me or someone else honestly dont be stupid ALWAYS carry rad-away and look for signs of the storm before it hits it always makes a decinct noise over all the others and usually can be avoided very easily as the others said sleeping or rad suit is best for staying in a settlement

Answer (score -2):

Well Rad Storms are easy to get away from you can either go inside a building (only buildings that take time to enter like a shop) or sleep. The way you can tell when ones coming by looking for strong winds and green clouds. Have fun and stay Rad free!

Comment: welcome to the arcade! While this is a good answer, it has already been said under a differant answer. please read the current answers before posting, and simply "upvote" an answer if it covers what you were going to post. duplicate answers are commonly frowned on and deleted.

Answer (score -2):

What I usually do is wait it out and deal with it. Sometimes, I wear a hazmat suit but not all the time. Its sometimes simpler to just pop in a rad-x or use a radaway after the storm.